# How to identify why a particular symbol gets pulled in by LLVM's ld.lld during static linking

Tags: c, linker, llvm, static-linking, newlib

I updated my [LLVM-based ARMv7em toolchain](https://github.com/burnpanck/docker-llvm-armeabi) from LLVM 8 to the just published release candidate 1 of LLVM 9. I haven't touched the compilation settings of newlib, which is the runtime library I use (version 3.1.0). Yet, since that change, when I link my microcontroller application against `libnosys.a` (the bare-metal runtime of newlib), I get the linker error:

> ld.lld: error: no memory region specified for section '.gnu.warning._close'

...and a number of other C-runtime symbols (`_getpid`, `_lstat`, `_isatty`, etc.).

Obviously, these functions would not be supported on a bare-metal system. I have learned that symbols of the form `.gnu.warning.SYMBOL` are used by the GNU tools to declare linker warnings that should be emitted when `SYMBOL` is being used. I have verified that those warning-symbols are found in `libnosys.a`, both when compiled with clang 8 and clang 9. My assumption is now that after the switch to **clang 9**, somehow those unsupported functions get pulled in, and since `ld.lld` doesn't know how to handle the GNU linker warnings, it fails because my linker script does not provide any section to place them. GNU ld would instead emit whatever warning is encoded for those symbols. However, either way, the symbols should not be used in the first place.

How can I find out why those symbols are now all of a sudden required in the final binary, i.e. what is it that depends on them? There must be an option in lld or objdump that does that, right?

Comment: You can use `nm` to see the symbols in each object. Grep for your symbol and the uppercase U (for undefined), e.g. `nm myobj.o | grep 'U.*close'`. Do it for all objects and libraries you link.

Comment: @n.m. doesn't that list the symbols _exported_ from each of those objects? I know which archive _exports_ those symbols, it's `libnosys.a`. However, they should not be needed in my program. I would like to know which object-file or even better which function _imports_ those symbols.

Comment: This lists *all* symbols. U stands for "undefined". There isn't such thing as explicit import of symbols in Unix, but you can consider undefined symbols "imported" for the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your first comment carefully enough - sorry. Therefore, your suggested approach allows me to identify which object files will cause the linker to include those symbols. Do you happen to know a way to utilise e.g. debug annotations to identify which functions within the object file ask for those symbols? Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: BTW: In fact, there is no Unix at play here, the question is about bare-metal development (no OS) on ARMv7em. It seems however that the normal binary object format for such toolchains is ELF nonetheless, so mostly the same tools and techniques apply, with the exception that there is no concept of dynamic linking.

Comment: No I don't know of such tool or method, but you can unarchive a static lib to its constituent objects (ar x library.a) and run nm on each object. Then disassemble the offending object and look at tge code.

Comment: Ok, I will try that - thanks for the suggestions!